# Remove EDIT button in Navigation Bar

Tags: experience-editor, editor-user-permissions

Can anyone know how I can remove "EDIT" button in Navigation Bar?

[image]

The navigation check-box fires the command "webedit:ToggleTreecrumb". Is there any way to deny "READ" access on this "EDIT" button? Any easiest way??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the item you're looking for is here:
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Page Editor/Navigation bar/Can Edit` in the `core` database.

By default, the `Sitecore Limited Page Editor` or `Sitecore Minimal Page Editor` roles seem to deny read privileges to that button.

Comment: Oh~ why I couldn't think of the security policies.. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jihyun, if answer is correct, please accept (green check mark) Amir's response